# python ssh automation script

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I would like to build an automation script for executing numerous commands on a remote server running linux, and check the "exit code" of each command and compare it with a statement

So far, as a absolutely beginner I have the following :

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.124.154', username='root', password='password')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')

for line in stdout:
    print line.strip('\n')

client.close()
```

Could you help me with a recommendation?

Comment: maybe use Ansible? it uses python and yaml.

Answer (score 0):

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@' +ip)
child.expect ('Login: ')
child.sendline (username)
child.expect ('Password: ')
child.sendline (password)
child.expect('#') # or expect `$`.
child.sendline('<your command>')
child.expect('#')
print child.before
```

Ref:http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Use `pexpect` its easier.

Comment: Thank you @vks !  What I would like to achieve with this script is to execute a command in a remote server (that is clear for me) and then verify the exit code of the command and if successful then execute next script

Comment: @vks, this is dangerous as currently written -- safer to use `pipes.quote(ip)` than `ip`; otherwise, you're in bad news if someone malicious feeds in an IP address of `$(rm -rf ~)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanx...didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vassal](https://github.com/Shawn-Shan/vassal) package, which is exactly designed for this.

All you need is to install vassal and do

```
from vassal.terminal import Terminal
shell = Terminal(["ssh username@host", "cd scripts", "python foo1.py", "python foo2.py"])
shell.run()
```

It will start an interactive window in python, and you can parse exit code from that. Also, it will save you authenticate credential and don't need to type them again and again.